# Integration Test with Typescript does not call callback into subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, integration-testing

I am writing an integration test to check the API on the backend.

The service is:

```html
export class Service {
    check(details: Credential, successBlock, errorBlock){
        let localString = "changeAuthenticationCredentialAPI/v2/authenticationCredential/check";


        let url = BASE_URL_SERVER + localString;
        let body = { details };
        let success = (data) => { 

            let _authorization = data.headers["Authorization"];
            let _clientID = data.body.relatedParty[0].id[0].value;
            let _token : Token = {};
            _token.token = _authorization;
            _token.clientId = _clientID;


            successBlock(_token);
        }

        this.post(success,errorBlock,url,body);
    }
    
    handleErrorSync(error) {
        try {
            return Observable.throw(JSON.parse(error._body));
        } catch (e) {
            return Observable.throw(error._body);
        }
    }

    
    post(success, error, url, body) {
        const options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders(HEADER_REQUEST)
        };

        let call = this.http.post(url, body,options).catch(this.handleErrorSync);
        this.makeCall(call, success, error);
    }

    makeCall(call, success, error) {
        call.flatMap(
            (result) => {

                if (this.responseIsOk(result)) {

                    return Observable.of(result);
                } else {

                    error(result);
                    return Observable.throw(result);
                }
            }
        ).subscribe(
            (result) => {

                 success(result); },
            (err) => {

                this.popupError(err);
                error(err);
            }
        );
    }
 }
```

On that the integration test looks like

```html
describe("authentication-credential-service.spec", () => {
    let backend : Service


    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                Service,
                { provide: ToastController, useClass: class { ToastController = jasmine.createSpy("ToastController"); } },
                { provide: ModalController, useClass: class { ModalController = jasmine.createSpy("ModalController"); } },
                FileTransfer,
                File
            ]
        });

        backend = TestBed.get(Service);
    }));



    it("should be created", inject([Service], (service: Service) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));


    describe("check", () => {
       it( "should answer 200 with the right token", async(inject([Service], (service:Service) => {
            let credential: Credential = {}; 
            credential.credentialType = "password";
            credential.usernameText = "user";
            credential.passwordText = "therightpassword";
            let _result : Token 
            let successBlock = ( (data) => { 
                _result = data
                expect(data).toBeDefined();
            } );
            let errorBlock = (error) => {
                expect(false).toBeTruthy();
            };
            service.check(
                credential,
                successBlock,
                errorBlock
            );
        })));
    });

})
```

The issue is that running the test the subscribe into the "makeCall" method is never called. So basically the test pass but only because no test is run.

The main purpose to use this is to check the consistency with the rest api of my backend but out there I have found only testing with mocked backend or mocked http reponses: perfect for Unit Testing but not for Integration tests.

One more thing: of course debugging the code it works and calls the subscribe.

Any clue? Thanks

Comment: where exactly in jasmine are you calling your call?

Comment: (you are right... fixing title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have find out that the issue was related to the fact that I was using the HttpClientModule and HttpClientTestingModule into the imports of the testBed configuration and that, somehow, was corrupting the integration test.
Removing the HttpClientTestingModule did the trick

```
describe("authentication-credential-service.spec", () => {
let backend : Service


beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientModule
        ],
        providers: [
            Service,
            { provide: ToastController, useClass: class { ToastController = jasmine.createSpy("ToastController"); } },
            { provide: ModalController, useClass: class { ModalController = jasmine.createSpy("ModalController"); } },
            FileTransfer,
            File
        ]
    });

    backend = TestBed.get(Service);
}));



it("should be created", inject([Service], (service: Service) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
}));


describe("check", () => {
   it( "should answer 200 with the right token", async(inject([Service], (service:Service) => {
        let credential: Credential = {}; 
        credential.credentialType = "password";
        credential.usernameText = "user";
        credential.passwordText = "therightpassword";
        let _result : Token 
        let successBlock = ( (data) => { 
            _result = data
            expect(data).toBeDefined();
        } );
        let errorBlock = (error) => {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        };
        service.check(
            credential,
            successBlock,
            errorBlock
        );
    })));
});
})
```